# Why is this a function of order O(1)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

I came across the function

$\int_1^{\gamma\varepsilon} \frac{e^{-2x}+e^{-2\gamma+2x}-2e^{-2\gamma}}{x}\,dx$ ,   $\varepsilon>0$

which is supposed to be of the order O(1) (big O) with respect to $\gamma$.

I cannot see where this comes from, could someone explain it?

Comment: Can you see why this function is bounded above with respect to $\gamma$?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Wouldn't I have to calculate the primitive function for that?

Comment: I suspect that integral does not converge for $\gamma\neq 0$ as $\lim_{x\to 0}e^{-2x}+e^{-2\gamma +2x}-2e^{-2\gamma}=1-e^{-2\gamma}\neq 0$.

Comment: I check in wolfram alpha, and it says integral does not converge.  Perhaps there is a typo in the question?

Comment: oh you are right, the lower integral limit is 1 and not 0, I just corrected it. Unfortunately I still don't see why it is of order O(1)

Comment: Do you want the small-$\gamma$ or large-$\gamma$ asymptotic behaviour?

Comment: As far as I understood it should be $\lim_{\gamma \to \infty} f(\gamma)<\infty$.

Comment: Try differentiating with respect to $\gamma$.

Comment: Can we assume that $0 < \varepsilon \leq 1$?

Answer (score 0):

*I replaced  $\gamma$ by $k$ to avoid confusion*

Assuming that you know the exponential integral function$$\int\frac{e^{-2x}+e^{-2k+2x}-2e^{-2k}}{x}\,dx=e^{-2 k } \left(e^{2k } \text{Ei}(-2 x)+\text{Ei}(2 x)-2 \log (x)\right)$$
$$I=\int_1^{k\epsilon} \frac{e^{-2x}+e^{-2k+2x}-2e^{-2k}}{x}\,dx=$$ $$e^{-2 k} \left(e^{2 k} \text{Ei}(-2 k \epsilon )+\text{Ei}(2 k \epsilon )-2 \log (k
   \epsilon )\right)-\text{Ei}(2) e^{-2 k}-\text{Ei}(-2)$$ Expanding as series around $k=0$ lead to
$$2 (\gamma +\log (2)-\text{Chi}(2))+2 k \left(\log \left(\frac{k \epsilon }{2}\right)+\text{Ei}(2)-\gamma \right)+$$ $$2 k^2 \left(-\text{Ei}(2)-\log \left(\frac{k \epsilon }{2}\right)+(\epsilon -2)
   \epsilon +\gamma \right)+O(k^3)$$